# Prove that $f(m,n)=\frac{(m+n−2)(m+n−1)}{2}+m$ from $\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}$ is one-to-one.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

Show that the polynomial function $$f(m,n)=(m+n−2)(m+n−1)/2+m $$ is one-to-one and onto. Both domain is $\Bbb Z^+\times \Bbb Z^+$, codomain are $\Bbb Z^+$.

I want to prove $f(a,b)=f(c,d) \longrightarrow (a=c \text{ and }b=d)$.
In the end,I got

$$a^{2} + b^{2}+2ab-a-3b=c^{2} + d^{2}+2cd-c-3d.$$

What should I do then? Lets $a>c$ but I have no clues.

Thanks

Comment: This is neither one-to-one nor onto.

Comment: An enarged question can be found there  :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707939/bijective-polynomials

Comment: If you write a short program to calculate the values for some test values of $m$ and $n$ you get this:
$$
1\  2\  4\  7\  11\  16\  22\  29\  37\  46  \\
3\  5\  8\  12\  17\  23\  30\  38\  47\  57  \\
6\  9\  13\  18\  24\  31\  39\  48\  58\  69  \\
10\  14\  19\  25\  32\  40\  49\  59\  70\  82  \\
15\  20\  26\  33\  41\  50\  60\  71\  83\  96  \\
21\  27\  34\  42\  51\  61\  72\  84\  97\  111  \\
28\  35\  43\ 52\  62\  73\  85\  98\  112\  127  \\
36\  44\  53\  63\  74\  86\  99\  113\  128\  144  $$
Should be enough for a hint.

Comment: @ProfessorVector The domain is positive integers.

Comment: Correct the title of your question, please, it is inconsistent with the body.

Comment: @bof i editd it and i found useful resources
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91323/620871
can some explain n−q=ad+(d(d+1))/2≥a+1? Thanks